# how to build ndk project with android studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

i m try to build ndk project in android studio but it will give me error like libopencv.so file not found.

yes I have included all the .so files Under jniLibs as instructed

and I am using the
Gradle 1.10
————————————————————

```
Build time: 2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number: none
Revision: 36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013

Android studio 0.5.3.
```

please let me know how can I resolve this.

Comment: Could you post your Android.mk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android.mk, add

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS     := $(LOCAL_PATH)/jniLibs/libopencv.so
```

Comment: i m suing android studio with gradle so there is no android.mk file is available in my project.

Comment: i think when we are using gradle insted of android.mk build.gradle is use to link .so file with the project

Comment: Have you checked whether you linked the so correctly? Is the library path correct?